# mapping a cube into a tetrahedron

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a cube with vertex at (0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,1), and a tetrahedron with vertex at (0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0).

How do I map the cube's coordinates to the tetrahedron bijectively? Are there an elegant function that would do it?

Note: on 2-dimension, to map a square to a triangle I can do f(x,y) = (x-xy/2,y-xy/2); I'm struggling to extend this to 3-dimension

Comment: It’s certainly possible: just scale each ray from the origin linearly to take the edge of the cube to the edge of the tetrahedron. I’m interested to see whether anyone can do it more elegantly than that.....

Comment: that's what I was thinking. But I'm not sure how to express that process by a function

Comment: You would have to write down separate functions depending which face of the cube and the tetrahedron each ray intersects. Like I said, not very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

A potentially useful observation is that the unit cube and unit simplex in any number of dimensions can be expressed in terms of the maximum norm $||\vec x||_M=\max(|x_i|)$ and the taxicab norm $||\vec x||_T=\sum_i|x_i|$, allowing us to make use of the convenient properties of norms:
$$
\text{Unit Cube:}\ \ \ \mathcal C=\{\vec x\in\mathbb R^d:x_i\ge 0, ||\vec x||_M\le 1\}
$$
$$
\text{Unit Simplex:}\ \ \ \mathcal S=\{\vec x\in\mathbb R^d:x_i\ge 0, ||\vec x||_T\le 1\}
$$
Note that your cube and tetrahedron are the $d=3$ case.

One way to transform between these shapes, then, is to map each vector $\vec x$ in the cube to a vector $\vec y$ in the same direction such that $||\vec x||_M=||\vec y||_T$. This gives us a simple function, which multiplies $\vec x$ by some positive constant $c(\vec x)$, for which we can find an expression.
$$\begin{align}
||\vec x||_M & = ||c\vec x||_T \\
||\vec x||_M & = |c|\ ||\vec x||_T \\
c & = \frac{||\vec x||_M}{||\vec x||_T}
\end{align}$$
This allows us to write down a function, taking care of the problematic zero case:
$$
f:\mathcal C\to\mathcal S,\ \ \ f(\vec x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{||\vec x||_M}{||\vec x||_T}\vec x & \vec x \neq \vec 0 \\
\vec 0 & \vec x = \vec 0
\end{cases}
$$
From here, showing that this is a bijection should be straightforward.